# Global keyboard shortcut to open an incognito window

Tags: google-chrome, windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts, taskbar

Is there a global shortcut to open an incognito window of Chrome?

I know that there is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> but that only works *in the context of Chrome* – not while in other applications.

I also know that you can drag the order of the applications in the task bar and then use <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (to <kbd>9</kbd>) in order to switch the focus to that application. Playing around with the keyboard, I've also noticed that you can open a window, too, with <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> … but that's not incognito. (<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> opens the application in admin mode – which is a nice discovery but also not what I'm looking for)

I'm searching for a solution that

- doesn't involve the mouse and
- doesn't mess with my <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> order,
- preferably involving the task bar (but that's optional).

Comment: Autohotkey or autoit should well suit your needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about creating a shortcut of Chrome, in properties append `chrome --incognito` into `target` textbox and assign a shorcut key?

Comment: Apparently (and surprisingly to me), this doesn't merge with an existing non-incognito taskbar slot. So I like this answer best!

Comment: Hm, I was so stuck on the taskbar that I didn't realize you were talking about global hotkeys for the shortcut file. (d'uh!) That works too, of course.

Answer (score 0):

I've got two solutions – but they're more like workarounds than solutions:

(1) <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> opens the taskbar context menu (I think it's also called "jump menu") and from there I can select it with <kbd>↓</kbd>.

(2) I can also open the "Run" window by pressing <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then type `chrome --incognito` the first time // hit <kbd>enter</kbd> on subsequent times.

But can anyone find something better?

Comment: Put chrome --incognito in batch file then assign any shortcut key to the batch file ?

Comment: Having tried that, I'm running into two issues: (a) Apparently, I can't attach .bat files to the taskbar. (b) Opening it from the Windows Explorer always triggers a security warning. Any ideas?

Comment: Might need 1 more step creating shortcut point to the batch file, then you can assign shortcut key at the properties. No need to attach to taskbar. I guess the security warning is asking for admin permission, set to run as admin should bypass the warning

Comment: The shortcut to a batch file won't stick either, unfortunately.

Comment: But (as I just found out) this does work if you set a global hotkey directly to the shortcut, when not involving the taskbar.